# Explicitly specify the sbt globals directory instead of using ~/.sbt

Tags: sbt

The documentation for [global sbt settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html) identifies `~/.sbt/` as the directory under which global plugins can be specified.

Unfortunately, I am working on two separate projects with cross-incompatible sets of global plugins.

If it were up to me, I would not have any global plugins, and explicitly list them in each project. But as it stands, I don't have said discretion.

Is there some way to launch sbt and explicitly specify different directories, i.e. `~/org1/.sbt/` and `~/org2/.sbt/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a JVM option 'sbt.global.base' and change the directory there. Its documented [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options)